# How to switch segments in Bar chart

Tags: palantir-foundry, foundry-workshop

I am creating a bar chart in Workshop and then segmenting by a column. This column has values as 'Yes' and 'No'.

Currently the bar chart shows 'Yes' in the upper section and 'No' in the lower section. I would like to switch the values and show 'No' in the upper section of the bar chart. Is it possible? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2):

One quick way to do this is to switch the `Y Axis` `Sort By` settings to `Key Ascending`:

[image: X Axis: Setting Key Ascending sort value]

This will cause the `No` bar to appear before the `Yes` bar:

[image: Workshop Yes/No Bar chart display]

Answer (score 1):

Simplest Way to Swap the segments is to give the names to Segments alphabetically. I was struggling there, but once I changed the segment names, It worked for me.

In my case previously segment was 'planned' and 'actual', so alphabetically 'actual' was at top and 'planned' at bottom.

Now I replaced segment names  from 'planned' to 'Future' and 'actual' to 'Past', so it swapped.